# Zero-points of solutions to differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Consider a simple differential equation: $$\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}=\displaystyle\frac{y}{x}\text{.}$$

By considering it as a separable equation, the solutions are $$y=Cx\text{,}$$ where $C$ is a constant.

But it seems to me that it is implicitly forbidden for $x$ to be $0$ in the original differential equation. Thus in my understanding, the solutions should be 
$$y=Cx,x\neq 0$$ instead of $$y=Cx\text{.}$$
Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

No you are wrong. It is enough that the limit satisfies the equation:

$$y'=C=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{Cx}{x}$$